# jQuery datepicker dynamic minDate distroys value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, mindate

I create 2 date pickers:

```
<input id="from" readonly value="05-10-2014">
<input id="to" readonly value="09-10-2014">

$("#from").datepicker();
$("#to").datepicker();
console.log($("#from").val() + ' - ' + $("#to").val());
```

Both dates are displayed correctly.

Now I set the minDate dynamically:

```
$("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", $("#from").val());
console.log($("#from").val() + ' - ' + $("#to").val());
```

2nd date disappears.

I am sure I miss something obvious. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat), the default date format is `mm/dd/yy`, but when you pass the value of `from` as a string it is not in that format which is causing the problem.

One possible solution is to set the dateFormat to the datepicker like

```js
$("#from, #to").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
console.log($("#from").val() + ' - ' + $("#to").val());

$("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", $("#from").val());
console.log($("#from").val() + ' - ' + $("#to").val());
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="from" value="05-10-2014">
<input id="to" value="09-10-2014">
```

Comment: Arun, you are right, this solved the problem, however I had these defaults:           `$.datepicker.setDefaults({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            showAnim: "slide",  All the other settings are applied fine. What was wrong with dateFormat?
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1
        });`

Comment: @Miklos may the said code is executed before the defaults are set?

Comment: I think you are right, if I set the default in the same file it works